# Java new Object[]{...} syntax

Tags: java, syntax, constructor

I don't recognize this kind of form Java syntax for constructor - granted I do very little Java now (taken from [there](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/bfe14aec1c223abc3253358bac34b503284467d9/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L1968)):

```
new PersistentArrayMap(new Object[]{formKey, form});
```

I was expecting something along the lines of `new Object(...)` as parameter. Could someone decompose the above line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new Object array `Object[]` initialised to `{obj1, obj2}`

Answer (score 1):

It is a way of declaring and initializing an array in java. A simpler example is the following:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
```